# Convert hexdump to byte sequence

Tags: linux, hex, hexdump

I am trying to register a specific program to run binaries that contain a magic number by using binfmt_misc on Linux.

This is accomplished by echo'ing a string in the format:

```
:name:type:offset:magic:mask:interpreter:flags
```

The Linux kernel documentation provides a few examples of this string at Documentation/binfmt_misc:

```
:i386:M::\x7fELF\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfb\xff\xff:/bin/em86:
:i486:M::\x7fELF\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x06:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfb\xff\xff:/bin/em86:
:DEXE:M::\x0eDEX::/usr/bin/dosexec:
:DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/local/bin/wine:
```

The magic number that I am interested in is displayed as `01eb` in emacs' hexl-mode:

```
00000000: 0000 01eb 0000 4d8f 0000 09a0 0000 0314  ......M.........
```

So far, I have:

```
:nine:M:$OFFSET:$MAGIC::/home/robb/nine/nine:
```

but I am not sure what values I need to replace `$OFFSET` and `$MMAGIC` with.

Comment: 1 for offset as you want to point to a second number and 01eb, which is your magic number. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts at the 3rd byte in the file.  Byte offsets start at zero, so `$OFFSET` should be 2.

Your `01eb` needs to be encoded in hexadecimal, so `$MAGIC` is `\x01\xeb`.  Your shell may require an extra backslash before every `\x` in order to escape it.